# Page is loading without styling initially in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

```css
@font-face { 
font-family: 'SF Pro Text'; 
src: url("../fonts/sfpro/SFProText-Regular.eot"); 
src: url("../fonts/sfpro/SFProText-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/sfpro/SFProText-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/sfpro/SFProText-Regular.svg#SFProText-Regular") format("svg"); 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal; 
}
```

When I'm loading a page in Firefox, it's loading a page without styling initially and loading with styling later automatically. This issue is happening only in Firefox not in Chrome or Safari

The Error I'm seeing in console is "Strict-Transport-Security: The connection to the site is untrustworthy, so the specified header was ignored."

The styling for the page are defined using font face URLs, so initially I tried disabling security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy in about:config. But despite of those errors in chrome the page is not having any intermediate loading.

Comment: Can you please share your html files code structure?

Comment: my structure is simple bootstrap cards loaded to display an e-commerce website. I believe you would like to see my fonts.css file structure 

@font-face {
  font-family: 'SF Pro Text';
  src: url("../fonts/sfpro/SFProText-Regular.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/sfpro/SFProText-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/sfpro/SFProText-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/sfpro/SFProText-Regular.svg#SFProText-Regular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; 
}

Comment: you can edit your question and write code in structure there.Its hard to get to know in comment

Comment: I have the same with most websites. I'm using Firefox 68.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows without any plugin loaded.